# nhibernate return result size cause the performace diffrence why?

Tags: nhibernate, pagination, performance

```
int pageSize = 36;
int pageIndex=1; 

IMultiQuery multiQuery = _session.CreateMultiQuery();
            multiQuery
                .Add(session.CreateQuery("select * from Smart_Products where " + where + " order by " + orderBy)
                    .SetFirstResult((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                    .SetMaxResults(pageSize))
                .Add(session.CreateQuery("select count(*) c from Smart_Products where " + where))
                .SetInt32("BrandId", brandId)
                .SetInt32("Flag", flag)
                .SetInt32("Status", 1);
            if (categoryId > 0)
            {
                multiQuery.SetInt32("CategoryId", categoryId);
            }
            IList results = multiQuery.List();
            foreach (var o in (IList)results[0])
                products.Add((ProductInfo)o);
            long count = (long)((IList)results[1])[0];
```

the same query when it paging a big data (ex.all row count 1000000 rows) get result fast ,but small data(ex.  all row count 5 rows) slow .

but I use sql profiler to trace the query ,and copy the query execute it in the msms it get data very fast use 50ms ,but use nhibernate to list the data when small data cost 10s even timeount , I have try some method that post in the site , clear cache and use statelesssession both didin't get word. can anyone body knows how to improve it .thank a ton.

Comment: whne you sau get all rows, what is the code that you use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are open to SQL injection you should never really use string concatenation when building a SQL statement. This will come back and bite you in the future. Please find time to look into this article [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and use parametrised queries instead.

Now for your question, some things to think about:-

1. Are the where clauses the same FOR every test?
2. Are indexes the cause of your problem?
3. Have you looked at the query plan in SSMS to see what is going on?
4. When you run the same SQL twice the second time it is cached on the SQL Server which is why you seeing a faster time second time around.

As a foot note it is not **NHibernate** causing the problem **BUT** it is SQL Server and the query you are running. I suggest you look at this first.

Comment: yes,I find the problem use sql profiler, when the data acount different case the execution plan different.